# Tengo 2 variables en mi controlador pero solo me jala uno

Tags: laravel

```
$ingreso=DB::table('INGRESO as i')
            ->join('PERSONA as p','i.ID_PER','=','p.ID_PER')
            ->join('DETALLE_INGRESO as di','i.ID_ING','=','di.ID_ING')
            ->select('i.ID_ING','i.FECHA_HORA','p.nombre','i.TIP_COMP','i.SERIE_COMP','i.NUM_COMP','i.impuesto','i.estado',DB::raw('sum(di.cantidad*PRECIO_COMPRA)as total'))
            ->where('i.ID_ING','=',$id)
            ->first();

        $detalles=DB::table('DETALLE_INGRESO as d')
        ->join('Articulo as a','d.ID_ARTI','=','a.ID_ARTI')
        ->select('a.nombre as Articulo','d.cantidad','d.PRECIO_COMPRA','d.PRECIO_VENTA')
        ->where('d.ID_ING','=',$id)
        ->get();

        return view("compras.ingreso.show",["ingreso"=>$ingreso,"detalles"=>$detalles]);
```

Mi problema es que solo lee la variable "ingreso".

```
{{Form::Open(array('action'=>array('IngresoController@show',$ing->ID_ING,$detalle->ID_ING)))}}
```

Comment: Mejora tu pregunta no se entiende.. Coloca tu controlador y el modelo.

Comment: en vez de una imagen, copia y pega el código, para darle formato necesitas dar 4 espacios por línea o selecciona todo el código y presionas control+K

Comment: añade por favor como estas intentando leerlas en tu vista

Answer (score 1):

Estás accesando a `$detalles` como si solo se tratase de un objeto cuando en realidad es un conjunto de registros, si solo esperas un registro usa:

```
$detalles=DB::table('DETALLE_INGRESO as d')
    ->join('Articulo as a','d.ID_ARTI','=','a.ID_ARTI')
    ->select('a.nombre as Articulo','d.cantidad','d.PRECIO_COMPRA','d.PRECIO_VENTA')
    ->where('d.ID_ING','=',$id)
    ->first();
```

Si vas a imprimir todos puedes hacer un foreach en blade, seria algo como:

```
@foreach($detalles as $det)
{{--código para mostrar la información--}}
@endforeach
```

Por otro lado creo que estas utilizando el mismo atributo en los parámetros `$ing->ID_ING,$detalle->ID_ING`, por qué no manejar algo como:

```
{{Form::Open(array('action'=>array('IngresoController@show',$ing->ID_ING,$ing->ID_ING)))}}
```

o

```
{{Form::Open(array('action'=>array('IngresoController@show',$ing->ID_ING,$detalle->first()->ID_ING)))}}
```